# How to open a dialog box in new tab?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a button in my application on clicking that it should open a new tab and prompt a jquery ui dialog box there. 
I manages to open new tab but dialog box opens in the old tab how to achieve that any help appreciated.

```
$("#linkButton").click(function(){ 
var url = "http://www.example.com";
 window.open(url, '_blank');
$('#testDialog').dialog('open');
   });
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot put the dialog box code on the old link. You must attach the code to the new link. In this case, your url is "http://www.example.com". If you put the code on the old link, the dialog box will appear on your old link. So..nothing wrong with your code. Your code work fine.

Comment: thanks for your answer but can you give me a example to do so.